# Are the correct Takadimi syllables notated in these exercises?

Tags: rhythm, meter, solfege

Did I put write in the correct takadimi syllables for these two exercises? Some of the syllables I wasn’t sure.

Exercise 350:

[image: Exercise 350]

And this one number 371:

[image: Exercise 371]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Exercise 350**

The first measure is correct: `ta` occurs at the beginning of each beat, and eighth notes indicate the beat in the 3/8 time signature.

The third measure is also correct: `ta` on the beginning of each beat; `di` on the halfway point of the beat.

The fourth measure is close, but `mi` is the wrong syllable. In should be `di`, because it occurs at the half beat.

```
X: 1
T: Exercise 350 hint
M: 3/8
K: none
[V:V1] B2 B3 B |
[V:V2] "ta"B"di"B "ta"B"di"B "ta"B"di"B
```

In the seventh measure, the triplet should be `ta-ki-da`. Three ordinary sixteenths would be `ta-ka-di`, but triplets are `ta-ki-da`.

**Exercise 371**

This exercise is mostly correct. The quarter-note / eight-note rhythm is `ta-da`, and dotted quarter-notes are `ta`. The two duplets in seventh measure should be `ta-di` rather than `ta-ki`. `ta-di` represent the 2-division of the beat.